# No bootable device with Ubuntu SSD installed

Tags: boot, ssd

I have replaced a hard drive with Windows with an SSD with Ubuntu but my computer now does not boot.

- Drive is plugged in, shows up in BIOS
- Drive is first in boot order
- Computer can boot from persistent USB
- Ubuntu is on first partition, swap is second, storage (NFTS) is third
- Drive and installation is fine, it has booted as an external drive before 
  -BIOS is on default settings
- Boot mode is UEFI, only other option is Legacy which neither works nor displays the error message.

Specific error is:
No Bootable Device

If any more details would be useful, please tell me. Not sure what else I can do to get it to boot.

Thank you in advance!

sudo parted -l output:

```
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type     File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  116GB  116GB   primary  ext4            boot, esp
 2      116GB   133GB  17.2GB  primary  linux-swap(v1)
 3      133GB   250GB  117GB   primary  ntfs
```

Comment: If booting in UEFI mode first partition should be the ESP - efi system partition FAT32 and drive should be gpt partitioned. post details: `sudo parted -l` It may have been using ESP on internal drive to boot?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: Done. How do I insert and ESP -efi partition f that is needed? Any way to do this without loosing what is already on the disk?

Comment: Check the Samsung web site for firmware updates for the SSD. Also, shouldn't your disk partition table be GPT (not msdos)?

Comment: That is why I suggest makeing it first partition when initially partitioning a drive. It does not have to be first if not too far into drive. I do not like moving the start of a partition as much higher risk of issues. But either way make sure you have good backups. You probably can just use gdisk to convert to gpt: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html  You may be able to use gparted to shrink sda1 by 500MB and create an ESP, FAT32 with boot flag. Or if gdisk code ef00. Not sure if that is too far into drive to cause issues or not.

Comment: Thanks, reparationing and using a different partitioning table worked.